# Class inheritance issue: Unsupported operand types for * 'float', and 'class'

Tags: python, class, object, inheritance

I am new to python, and exploring the class inheritance feature. In my code attached here, I have two classes, by the names "Waveguide" and "taper". The attributes for the waveguide object (WG) created by "Waveguide" class takes in three variables of which I just need the "width" attribute to be passed on to the "taper" child class. The code uses inheritance with "super".
Now when I run the code with the last two lines commented/ignored, {*tap=Taper(2,10,1), print(tap.tap_gen())}*, I dont see any error and the wg_pts are returned. But when I try to run the entire code and generate tap_pts using **tap.tap_gen()**, I get an error showing:

*Traceback (most recent call last):
File "d:\gdsfactory-6.37.3\gdsfactory-6.37.3\gdsfactory\ZP files\Passives.py", line 35, in 
print(tap.tap_gen())
File "d:\gdsfactory-6.37.3\gdsfactory-6.37.3\gdsfactory\ZP files\Passives.py", line 29, in tap_gen
tap_pts=[pya.Point(-0.5*self.taplen,0.5*self.width),pya.Point(0.5*self.taplen,0.5*self.w1),pya.Point(0.5*self.taplen,-0.5*self.w1),pya.Point(-0.5*self.taplen,-0.5*self.width)]
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'float' and 'taper'*

The code refers to the line where the * operator is used, and these lines of the code are highlighted in the script below. I  don't understand why this is happening. Any leads are appreciated.

I tried the script to pass on the value of the single attribute "width" from my parent class "Waveguide" to pass on to the child class "taper". But the error pops up at the site where * is used. The issue does not happen with the WG object created with the Waveguide class, but only happens with the "taper" child class, making it a potential issue of code format.
[Python script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/udeqm.png)
[Python script highlighted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6BKX3.png)

Comment: Please update your question with your actual code as text. I can't see where the problem lies from the image.

Answer (score 0):

The highlighted line contains many operations. I'd recommend splitting the command into several lines so you can know exactly what part is causing what error. Ultimately, the issue is caused because an instance of taper is being multiplied by a float.

What is the types of the variables you reference in the highlighted line? The most likely scenario is that one of the referenced variables (`self.taplen`, `self.w1`, `self.width`) is a taper.

The other possibility is that the function `pya.Point()` performs a multiplication with a variable it expects to be either a `float` or a `taper`, but it gets the other. What does the documentation say about what kind of arguments `pya.Point()` can accept? Are you passing the correct object type to the function?

Since you're using vscode, I'd recommend getting comfortable with they python debugger. If you place a breakpoint at line 29 and add the expression `[type(x) for x in [self.taplen,self.width,self.w1]]` to the watch list, it will very quickly give you the types of all of your variables :)

Comment: Thank you! I checked that the attribute "width" which is borrowed from the parent class "Waveguide" is not a type "int". For this, I used __type(self.width)__, while the rest __w1__, __taplen__ attributes are of type int. The __pya.Point__ accepts integer type arguments. As you can see, the type function returns "width" which is a borrowed attribute to belong to a class '__main__.taper'. How can I resolve this to make "width" like other regular "int" type?

Comment: You can use type casting to transform variables into new types. This is a pretty common feature in languages. In python, this is done via type(var), so in your case you would do int(self.width). Depending on what type self.width is, it may be possible that it will not support typecasting to int (the interpreter casts variables to int by calling the .__int__() method, so if self.width does not have a .__int__() attribute, it can't be cast to an integer). In that case, you will have to perform a sort of manual cast by looking at the attributes of self.width and defining a behavior yourself.

Comment: Thank you very much. I found that the "super" function is causing this issue. In this code snippet, when I use another format of inheritance for the child class from the parent without the super function, I am able to resolve the issue.

Comment: Thank you very much. I found that the "super" function is causing this issue. In this code snippet, when I use another format of inheritance for the child class from the parent without the super function, I am able to resolve the issue. This means in the original code instead of using __super().__init__(self, width)__, I have used __Parent class.__init__(Self, attributes)__